# Convert PyQt5 Desktop App to IOS/MacOS app developed using python

Tags: python, ios, macos, pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

I want to convert a Desktop GUI app designed using PyQT5 desinger which was converted to python code using pyuic5 and now i am looking for information on how this Desktop Gui App can be converted to iOS/MacOS.

I tried pyqtdeploy those commands given below runs fine but it doesn't generate xcode related files which allows it run on iOS/MacOS.

pyuic5 -x maintabbedwidget2.ui -o ClickProvision.py

pip install pyqtdeploy

pyqtdeploy GUITransformation.pyd

pyqtdeploy-build GUITransformation.pyd

Above methods are not generated xcode related files not sure what i am doing wrong but i got a folder structure like below after running pyqtdeploy-build.

Is there any other method using which i can used to convert PyQT5 generated python code to make it run as iOS/MacOS APP.

```
OCIGUI.pdy    build-macos-64
vinodhbabu$ cd build-macos-64/
build-macos-64 vinodhbabu$ ls
Makefile            frozen_bootstrap_external.h    pyqtdeploy_main.cpp        resources
OCIGraphicalIInterface.pro    frozen_main.h            pyqtdeploy_start.cpp
frozen_bootstrap.h        pdytools_module.cpp        pyqtdeploy_version.h

build-macos-64 vinodhbabu$
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to iOS/MacOS app"? Pyqtdeploy creates C++ code and that implies not being iOS/MacOS native.

Comment: if you check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=85v6Fyb10nw it explains how to convert pyqt5 generated apps to work on IOS Device. I was checking if there is any other way of achieving the same for python.

Comment: So your target is actually iOS? Afaik pyqt apps run smoothly on MacOS.

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: @vinodh have you succeeded with building mac app using pyqtdeploy??